# Pretrained alexnet in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, image-classification

I want to use pretrained Alexnet for transfer learning. I dont see its available in Keras library.
Am I missing something here?
Other Alternative I see here is to create model and

1. load pretrained weight
2. train from scratch

Training from scratch using imagenet dataset is not possible for me due to resource constraint.
Loading pre-trained weight will work.
Would you provide any pointers for getting the pretrained weight for Alexnet?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, Keras does not (officially) seem to offer a pre-trained AlexNet model. PyTorch, on the other hand, does. If you are willing to use a different framework for the task, you can use PyTorch. You can retrieve a pre-trained version of the AlexNet like so:

```
import torchvision.models as models
alexnet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
```

You can find the list of available pre-trained models [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html), and a transfer learning tutorial for image classification [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html).

Hope that answers your question!